# Getting "Server tag is not well formed" error

Tags: asp.net

```
<th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox ID="UtilityChanged('<%# Eval("id") %>')" runat="server" Enabled="true" onchange="UtilityChanged('<%# Eval("id") %>');" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/></th>
```

ERROR: server tag is not well formed.....I cant seem to debug it...any help guys?

---

EDIT:
I commented out the ochange and I am still getting the error;

Directly above this code I am binding to a different field using the same dataSource. Which works fine...

```
<th style="width:200px;"><%# Eval("Name") %></th>
```

why doesnt(below) work.....

```
 <th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox ID='UtilityChanged<%# Eval("id") %>' runat="server" Enabled="true" Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>'/></th>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a bit of string concatenation in the `onchange` attribute:

```
<th style="width:200px;"><asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Enabled="true" onchange='<%# "UtilityChanged" + (Eval("id")) %>' Checked='<%# Convert.ToBoolean(Eval("Checked")) %>' /></th>
```

Comment: onchange is working fine its the ID of the checkbox i am trying to bind to, please see edit...thanks for reply

Comment: Ah, you can't assign values like that to the server-side ID attribute.

Comment: A suggestion: I assume you need to refer to the `ID` attribute client side. Unfortunately, WebForms may change the server-side ID in the emitted HTML (view source of the page in your browser to see this). Could you add another attribute like `data-id` and assign `Eval("id")` to that - which you could then refer to client-side instead of `ID`?

Comment: Im only after figuring that out, im using name instead thanks for the help man, much appreciated

Comment: No problems - the joy of WebForms eh ;)